# if user does not add http to their link

Tags: javascript, html, http

I have a site where users can share their social media accounts. but if they dont add the http the link shows to www.mysite.com/www.theirsite.com and then just rediects back to my site.

```
<a href="{{channel.facebook_page}}" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"  title="{{channel.channel_name}} On FaceBook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" style='color:#ee6f00'></i></a>
```

i know most will say just add the http as a post to the link like href="http://{{channel.facebook_page}}

But I cant do that as some people do add it then some dont. I have lots of forms where the input is for these fields and dont want the hassle of changing all the forms.

is there something I can do on the display link to solve this issue.

Comment: so detect if it is missing and add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, then you just test whether the user added it or not, and, if not, add it:

```
function fixHTTP(url) {
    var regex = /^https{0,1}:\/\/.*/;
    return regex.exec(url) ? url : ('http://' + url);
}

// use it like:
var url1 = 'www.google.es';
var url2 = 'https://www.google.es';
fixHTTP(url1); // returns 'http://www.google.es'
fixHTTP(url2); // returns 'https://www.google.es'
```

Comment: This is vanilla JavaScript, you don't need any library for this.

Comment: Exactly what @enf0rcer said